# SSIS package fast in visual studio but slow in SQL Agent job

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I've developed a **SSIS** package in which I have a **data flow task** that inserts data from one table to another (with a **left outer join**) in a **sql server 2014** Data Base. When I run it from Visual Studio "manually" it runs in approx **1 minute**.
I have a **job** scheduled to run twice a day, and in this job this process takes approx **2 hours**.

I read that changing the **Delay Validation** in the connection properties to "True" should help it, but it did not.

I could not find any other explanation for this phenomenon.

Appreciate your help!

Comment: You need to tell us: Is this Visual Studio _on_ the same server that the job runs on? If not, that is one variable that could account for it. run `sp_Who` on the source database to see if the issue is there. Is your data flow a simple source and destination or do you have transformations in there.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, but the visual studio is local in my pc, so I don't think it's the same server. Regarding the data flow - it's a simple table as source and destination.The transformation I make is only to add a  new column that does not exist in the source table. I do it with merge join from another simple table.

Comment: When you connect to a server is SSMS to then go and accessthe SQL Agent, what is that server? Is it also your local PC? I'm guessing it is.

Comment: It's not my pc. I'm connecting to a specific server and not to the local server in my pc.

Comment: When you run the package in visual studio it's running on your _local PC_. So the data goes from whatever _source_ you have, to your local PC, then to whatever _target_ you have. When you run it in SQL Agent it runs on the "specific server". The data goes from your _source_ to the _server_ then to the _target_. It could be that network is much better in the first case. So you need to understand the _four_ servers involved in this. Your source server, your target server, your laptop, your SQL Server, and understand the network traffic. That _could_ be it or it might have nothing to do with it

Comment: Also please clarify what version of SQL Server, and do you have any transformations in your data flow? Is the left outer join in your query?

Comment: Sure. SQL Server 2014 Enterprise 64-Bit. In my data flow I don't have any other transformations, only left outer join between the source table and another table. A straight forward left outer join between a PK in the second table and a column in the source table.

Comment: Just to be completely clear: this left outer join is _in the source SQL_ right? It's not a SSIS outer join is it?

Comment: It was in the source SQL , but the problem was still there, so I tried to change it to SSIS with a merge join. It did not help either. For now, it's still in the SSIS, but I can change it. But as I said before, it was at the beginning in the source SQL.

Comment: No - leave it in the source SQL. There's less to go wrong. I suggest you use `sp_who` or sp_WhoIsActive` to monitor the source (and target) SQL Server while it's running and see what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and it turned out it had to do with the proxy credential which was used by the SQL Server Agent Job. Simply changing the proxy with a new one solved the problem